# Generic convert

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to be able to convert a type that inherits from a `Role` to a `Role`.  For example, a `RoleWithApiResources`.

My `Convert` function looks like this right now, but does not compile:

```
public static Role Convert<T>(T role) where T : Role
{
    var result = new Role();
    result.Id = T.Id;
    result.Name = T.Name;
    result.Description = T.Description;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your model if you need to convert something that derives from `Role` (i.e. *it **is** a `Role` already*) into a `Role`. This is why we have inheritance in the first place. Seems highly redundant to me.

Comment: Spender is correct; *your function should be an identity*. If you need to convert a derived type to a base type using something other than a reference or boxing conversion, then something is probably very wrong.

Comment: @EricLippert I have no idea what I was thinking.  To your point, this function is unnecessary.  I will just cast my object down to the base type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your constraint, you should use `role` instead of `T` (and use the object initializer to simplify the code):

```
public static Role Convert<T>(T role) where T : Role
{
    var result = new Role
    {
        Id = role.Id,
        Name = role.Name,
        Description = role.Description
    };

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your function you need to use the 'role' parameter instead of T

For example:

```
public static Role Convert<T>(T role) where T : Role
{
    var result = new Role();
    result.Id = role.Id;
    result.Name = role.Name;
    result.Description = role.Description;

    return result;
}
```